# Is the word "as" a preposition in the sentence "He ran as though his life depended on it"?

Tags: prepositions, syntax, functions

Is the word "as" a preposition in the sentence "He ran as though his life depended on it"?

I'm 99% sure that it's not, due to the verb "depended". I just want to be *100%* sure.

Answer (score 1):

The word "as" is not a preposition. The combination "as though" is a conjunction.

[American Heritage Dictionary "as though"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=as%20though)
conj.
As if:   *looked as though they had been quarreling.*

[Merriam-Webster "as though"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20though)
as if